# In Java, how to copy all the files in a directory using the Path object?

Tags: java, path

Please be kind, I'm new to Java.  I'm looking for a way to copy all the files from a source directory to a target directory using the Path object. I looked around and saw older solutions to this problem (using the older java,io), but not the (newer java.nio) Path object.  Here's what I have so far.

```
// copyFiles - Copies files from source directory/folder to destination directory/folder
// Requires:
//      import java.nio.file.Path;
//      import java.nio.file.Paths;
//      import java.nio.file.Files;
public static void copyFiles(String OSType, String source, String destination)throws IOException {
    Path sourcePath = Paths.get(source);
    Path destinationPath = Paths.get(destination);

    if (!Files.exists(sourcePath) || !Files.isDirectory(sourcePath)) {
        System.out.println("Source directory/Folder " + source + " does not exists.");
    } else if (!Files.exists(destinationPath) || !Files.isDirectory(destinationPath)) {
        System.out.println("Destination directory/Folder " + source + " does not exists.");
    } else if (Files.list(sourcePath).count() > 0) {

        List<Path> sourceLocationContent = new ArrayList<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourcePath)) {
            for (Path file : stream) {
            // System.out.println(file.getFileName());
            sourceLocationContent.add( file.getFileName());
        }

        System.out.println("sourceLocationContent.size() = " + sourceLocationContent.size());
        for (int i=0 ; sourceLocationContent.size() > i ; i++){
            System.out.println("sourceLocationContent.get("+i+") = " + sourceLocationContent.get(i));
            Files.copy(sourceLocationContent.get(i),destinationPath);
        }
    } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Source directory/Folder " + source + " is empty.");
}
```

}

Comment: Consider posting [mcve]. Most of the code posted in not relevant to the question "how to copy all the files in a directory using the Path object?
"

Comment: [This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_copy_Path_source_Path_target_CopyOption_options_.htm)  may help

Answer (score 0):

Here's my slightly long code that does this.
The example can be run right away, just 
make sure to provide it src and dest directories.

```
    package copytodir;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Chol
 */
public class CopyToDir {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter source: ");
        String srcDir = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter destination: ");
        String destDir = keyboard.nextLine();
        copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
    }

    public static void copyDirectory(String sourceDir, String destDir) throws IOException {
        Path sourceDirPath = Paths.get(sourceDir);
        Path destDirPath = Paths.get(destDir);

        Files.copy(sourceDirPath, destDirPath, REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.list(sourceDirPath)
        .forEach(pathOfFile -> {
            try {
                copyFile(pathOfFile, Paths.get(destDirPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + pathOfFile.toFile().getName()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CopyToDir.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void copyFile(Path srcFile, Path destFile) throws IOException {
        Files.copy(srcFile, destFile, REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of the strings to `copyDirectory` you can just change them to `(Path sourceDirPath, Path destDirPath)` then remove the local variables inside the function. That would still work, and it's closer to what your question asks.

Comment: Thanks!  You've give me a different angle to approach this problem.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An old post, but I've seen plenty of similar posts, so I'll share nonetheless. The following has become a common used idiom for what you want to do.

```
public static void copyDir( Path src, Path dst ) throws IOException {

    Files.walkFileTree( src, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
            Files.createDirectories( dst.resolve( src.relativize( dir ) ) );
            return CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile( Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
            Files.copy( file, dst.resolve( src.relativize( file ) ), REPLACE_EXISTING );
            return CONTINUE;
        }
    } );
}
```